# Javascript framework for Dynamic Form builder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

My organization is developing a web based application for digitization of scientific organizations. The users across various labs perform many experiments and enter them into forms. Now each lab have different template for variety of experiments. For example: Result Entry template for biological experiments in lab A may differ from those of lab B.

The template would consist of labels and input elements such as textbox, textarea, combo, tables etc. The values entered in these would be stored in corresponding fields in database. Further, a printed report same as the template used for result entry is also needed. These templates are not pre-decided and may change over time.

In order to overcome this and reduce time taken to customize the form every time, we are considering developing an interactive web based form builder which can be predefined for each lab by lab administrators and used by the scientists for entry. But the result entry forms may get complex often requiring nested tables, multiple columns and binding to database for certain elements (such as combo, or default values).

I have explored a few JS frameworks for the same such as [DojoToolKit](https://dojotoolkit.org/), [JQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/), [SproutCore](http://sproutcore.com/) etc. But since I do not have much experience with JS frameworks, I was wondering which of them would be good for my task and if there are there any existing utilities (preferably open source) for such purpose.

Note: I am using struts for my web application with Postgres as the database.

Comment: what's the backend powered by? I've found that this sort of thing is better generated usings a backend tech such as GWT or vaadin. Have you though about designing the forms in json, then it can be written in any way and rendered regardless fo framework/tech?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest that rather then design the forms in javascript/GUI that they are designed in json, that way your users can design the forms with any tool they see fit, and have it render uniformly, for example:

```
"form" : {
  "title" : "some new form"
  "elements" : [
    {
      "type" : "text",
      "name" : "user_name",
      "id" : "user_name",
      "label" : "please enter your user name"  
    }
  ]
}
```

You can then pass the same json to your frontend to render the form, and to your backend service to handle the form post/submission.

This approach also means that you can update/change your backend or frontend stack and still be able to handle the json data in the same way

(so if you decide to use dojo then change to jquery, the input doesnt need to change)

You can of course still build a web based generator gui to create the json data, where I'd suggest jquery and jquery UI would be the easyest way to do it.

You'd need to build a UI that allows you to add/update the json output, things like buttons to add a text input, inputs to add text fields and names, here's a [very simple basic demo](http://jsfiddle.net/42c6L4jm/).  input some text into the text name field then generate the json, you'll see in your console that the json object has been updated

UPDATE: if you want to go down the road of a prebuilt solution then you could try: [jquery form builder](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?tV8PvXfp)

Comment: thanks. But how do I generate the JSON (or XML) ? I am not sure about how to go about designing such a utility where user can drag and drop elements, they are converted to JSON and then used elsewhere.

Comment: added with a very basic fiddle. input into the text name

Comment: @atmd is it a good approach to construct the JSON on backend when user click "generate json" button? I am using .Net (C#) as backend to support our application.

Comment: Yes generating on the backend is a perfectly good approach. I've done it frontend in the jsfiddle soley to demo the change.

Comment: @krammer updated my answer wirth a jquery plugin to generate the form, you'd then need to convert that to json (if it doesnt already have an export funciton)

Comment: @atmd thanks. I looked at vaadin. Moreover, I am more comfortable with Java. Would you recommend vaadin or dojo for my task ?

Comment: depends where you want to do the transformation. Vaadin would be server side and you'd use rpc to send it to the front end. It would certainly be the most stright forward way to do it. You can then keep your frontend light and 'stupid' and simply spit out what vaadin gives it

Comment: that updated link no longer works FYI.